# Inserting range of dates in mysql db

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a mysql database in which I am trying to insert consecutive dates for one year (starting 7-1-2012) and only want weekday dates inserted using php. Below is the code I have so far but get an error message: unexpected 'Y' (T_STRING) at the "values (date("Y-m-d", $i)" code on line 11. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
$startdate = mktime(0,0,0,7,1,2013); 
$enddate = strtotime("+1 years", $startdate); 

// now we have a lower number and an upper  
// number, we can loop to give dates 
echo $startdate;
echo $enddate;

for($i=$startdate; $i<=$enddate; $i=strtotime("+1day",$i)) {
    if ($i >=2 && $i<=6){
        $insert_query = "insert into schedstats(schedDate, schedRep, reqPOD) values (date("Y-m-d", $i), 2, "All Day")";
        mysql_query($insert_query) or die ("Error in query: $insert_query. ".mysql_error());
    }
}
```

Comment: Date in query is meant to be php function, you have to remove it from the string like this ...values ('".date("Y-m-d", $i)."', 2...

Comment: Out of interest, why are you doing this?  Up to you of course, but it would not be best practice for most date-using applications.  if you give a little more detail you might get some helpful improvement suggestions too.

Comment: I have a scheduling program in which one of the participants is not able to work most of the year. To make that person unavailable, I need to insert into the table each weekday's date for one year and mark that person unavailable. Then, when the person is available, those dates would be deleted from the db and that person would then be included as an available employee in the available list provided the user. The person this affects might only have 30 days out of the year they are available. I welcome any suggestions. I found another problem identified in 1 Answer below. Thanks for asking.

Answer (score 0):

You either need to use the opposite quote style inside your other quote style, or escape your quotes, like `\"` or `\'`, within a String. You should also use MySQL DATE AND TIME FUNCTIONS within MySQL.
    $insert_query = "insert into schedstats(schedDate, schedRep, reqPOD) values (date("Y-m-d", $i), 2, "All Day")";
should be something like:

```
$insert_query = "INSERT schedstats(schedDate, schedRep, reqPOD) VALUES (DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME($i), '%Y-%m-%d'), 2, 'All Day')";
```

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html for more details.

Side Note:
Variables, like `$i` will be evaluated inside double quotes. Single Dimensional Numeric Arrays can also be evaluated in double quotes, like `"What $ary[1] more info here";`. If you want to put a Single Dimensional Associative Array inside double quotes, that can be done like `"What {$ary['key']} more info here";`. If you are putting another String inside a String, imagine that the String your putting in's quotes are being pealed off. So, if the quotes themselves need to be in the String you're putting the other String into, put them back on. If you can't get your results through any of the double quote methodologies, use concatenation, like `'What '.$ary[0]['key'].' more info here';`. Since PHP will try and evaluate everything inside double quotes it may be technologically faster to use single quotes. I use double quotes all the time and it works fine, though.

Comment: Thank you all. I think I see another problem and I am not sure how to deal with it. I need to identify the day of the week of 'i' in the if statement and needs to do that. How would I go about that?

Comment: I have figured out all but one problem. Below is the code and it works except when I insert the date into the mysql db, the date shows up as 0000:00:00. What is wrong?  ` for($i=$startdate; $i<=$enddate; $i=strtotime("+1day",$i)) {
 $newDate = strftime("%Y-%m-%d", $i);
 $newDay = date("w", $i);
 
 if ($newDay >=1 && $newDay <=5){
        $insert_query = "insert into schedStats(schedDate, schedReporterId, reqPartOfDay, schedStatus) values ($newDate, 2, 'All Day', 'Booked')";
    mysql_query($insert_query) or die ("Error in query: $insert_query. ".mysql_error());
 }
}`

Comment: Sorry. The date inserted into the database is 0000-00-00

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql> SELECT ADDTIME('2007-12-31 23:59:59.999999', '1 1:1:1.000002');
    -> '2008-01-02 01:01:01.000001'

mysql> SELECT ADDTIME('01:00:00.999999', '02:00:00.999998');
    -> '03:00:01.999997'
```

Source: [dev.mysql.com: function_addtime](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_addtime)

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are not getting any element inserted, is that you were checking the var `$i` to be between 2 and 6 (Monday and Friday?). The point is that `$i` is initialized to a unixtime timestamp, and that's a very high value.

First I did, was to rename `$i` as `$tstamp`, so it's more clear what it really is. Then the function `isWeekDay()` checks whether `$tstamp` is a weekday. Finally, as `schedDate` is a DATE field, you need to convert `$tstamp` from a unixtimestamp to a MySQL Date.

NOTE: [According to PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), weekdays ranges between 1 and 5.

```
<?

$startdate = mktime(0,0,0,7,1,2013);
$enddate = strtotime("+1 years", $startdate);

// now we have a lower number and an upper  
// number, we can loop to give dates 
echo "startdate: $startdate\n";
echo "enddate: $enddate\n";

for ($tstamp = $startdate; $tstamp <= $enddate; 
        $tstamp = strtotime("+1day",$tstamp)) {
    if (isWeekDay($tstamp)) {
        $insert_query = "insert into schedstats(schedDate, schedRep, reqPOD) 
            values (from_unixtime($tstamp), 2, 'All Day')";
        mysql_query($insert_query) 
            or die ("Error in query: $insert_query. ".mysql_error());
    }
}

function isWeekDay($tstamp) {
    $weekday = date("w", $tstamp);
    return $weekday > 0 && $weekday < 6;
}

?>
```

Comment: Thank you but the code inserted into the MYSQL db is still 0000-00-00. The schedDate is formatted as date in the db. Rows are inserted but still no valid date.

Comment: OK, you need to convert $tstamp, which is a unix timestamp, to a MySQL Date. Edited my answer to reflect that change.

Comment: When I run this I get the following error message: FUNCTION from_unixtimestamp does not exist

Comment: OK, sorry, the name of the function is not from_unixtimestamp is from_unixtime http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime

Comment: Thank you so very much for your help and patience. I am somewhat new to php & mysql and I am just starting to work with times. Still a bit confused but will study the suggestions on this post. Thanks again.